# Printing a webpage that contains a salary calculation using javascript, mysql, php and html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a salary slip for an employee. I am able to retrieve salary information from the database and display in on a page. I am also able to calculate the leaves salary deduction from the salary using a javascript function and pass it on to the html page. But, when I give a print command through a print button on the page through printer, the leave salary deduction values are not getting printed. Any help in this regards will be greatly appreciated as I am struggling with this issue for the couple of days.

HTML Code:

```
echo '<div id = "divToPrint">';

        echo '<form name = "formName1"><table>';

echo '<tr><td colspan = "9"><B>Salary Break Up:</B></td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td colspan = "6">Basic:</td><td>'.$rows[13].'</td><td></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td colspan = "6">DA:</td><td>'.$rows[14].'</td><td></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td colspan = "6">HR:</td><td>'.$rows[15].'</td><td></td></tr>';

            $a = $rows[13]+$rows[14]+$rows[15];

            echo '<td colspan = 7"><B>Gross Salary(A):</B></td><td><B>'.$a.'</B></td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td colspan = "8">&nbsp;</td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td colspan = "8"><B>Deductions:</B></td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td colspan = "6">Provident Fund:</td><td>'.$rows[16].'</td><td></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td colspan = "6">Income Tax:</td><td>'.$rows[17].'</td><td></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td colspan = "6">EMI:</td><td>'.$rows[18].'</td><td></td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td colspan = "6">Loan:</td><td>'.$rows[19].'</td><td></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td colspan = "6">Other Deduction:</td><td>'.$rows[21].'</td><td></td></tr>';

            $deduction = $rows[16]+$rows[17]+$rows[18]+$rows[19]+$rows[21];

            echo '<tr><td>Leaves Taken</td>';

echo '<td><select name = "leaves_taken" onChange="setForm2Value()">';

                echo '<option value = "">Select...</option>';
                echo '<option value = "0">0</option>';
                echo '<option value = "1">1</option>';
                echo '<option value = "2">2</option>';
                echo '<option value = "3">3</option>';
                echo '<option value = "4">4</option>';

echo '</select></td>';

            echo '<td colspan = "4">Leave Salary Deduction</td>';

            echo '<td><input type = "text" name = "leave_sal_deduction" id = "leave_sal_deduction" border = "0"></td><td></td></tr>';

            echo '<td colspan = 7"><B>Total Deductions(B):</B></td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "total_deduction" id = "total_deduction"></td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td colspan = "8">&nbsp;</td></tr>';


            $d = "Net Salary(A - B): ";
            echo '<td colspan = "7"><B>'.$d.'</B></td>';
            echo '<td><input type = "text" name = "total_salary" id = "total_salary"></td></tr>';

        }

    echo '</table></form>';

        echo '</div>';
```

Javascript Code:

```
function PrintDiv() {    

var divToPrint = document.getElementById('divToPrint');

var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank');

popupWin.document.open();

popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">');

popupWin.document.write(divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');

popupWin.document.close();

            }
```

Leave Salary Calculation using JavaScript:

```
function setForm2Value() {

    var selectedItem      = document.formName1.leaves_taken.selectedIndex;
    var selectedItemValue = document.formName1.leaves_taken.options[selectedItem].value;
    var selectedItemText  = document.formName1.leaves_taken.options[selectedItem].text;

    if (selectedItem != 0) {
        //document.formName1.textboxName1.value = selectedItemText;


        //Getting Gross Salary
        var net_sal = "<?php echo $a ?>";
        var net_sal1 = parseInt(net_sal);


        //Calculation of Leave Salary Deduction
        var abc = ((net_sal1 / 30) * selectedItemValue).toFixed(2);
        var abc1 = parseInt(abc) ;  


        //Printing Leave Salary Deduction
        $("#leave_sal_deduction").val(abc1);

        //Calculating Total Deduction
        var d = "<?php echo $deduction ?>";
        var d1 = parseInt(d);

         var b = parseInt(d1 + abc1);

        //Displaying Total Deduction
        $("#total_deduction").val(b);



        //Calculating Total Payable Salary
        var total = (net_sal1 - b);
        $("#total_salary").val(total);
```

[image: Print preview of the page through printer. Not Able to get the leave salary deduction and net salary values printed on a page using print method through a printer.]

Comment: When you print, your page get loaded again from initial state so your previously typed data won't appear there. It would be better if you do the calculation on backend or another solution would be to add every input value as a query parameter right after you typed something and in case of refresh (or print) the inputs should get their values from there and do the calculation right after.

Comment: Why do you need to reload the page to print the slip?

Comment: I am just trying to print the page through printer using an onclick method. The leave salary deduction and the net salary calculation are done in the javascript and the result is passed on to the textfileds. When printing the page through printer, it is printing all the information except leave salary deduction and netsalary (both calculated and derived from a javascript function).

Comment: Oh my… So many `echo`s! You should take a look at the "Heredoc" syntax. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: @TakitIsy I do apologize for the lengthy and repetitive code. But if it makes sense, I am just a newbie when it comes to php. Thank you for the heads up. Will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

set the value of an element dose not update the html. to update the html you can use 
object.setAttribute 
for example to update the html of the element leave_sal_deduction

```
document.getElementById('leave_sal_deduction').setAttribute("value",document.getElementById('leave_sal_deduction').value);
```

you can add this to your print function before getting html of the divToPrint